# Best way to implement addValueChangeListener for a complex Vaadin Component?

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin, event-listener

I have a rather complex Vaadin component with seven different inputs:

```
public class MyComponent extends VerticalLayout
    implements HasValue<ValueChangeEvent<MyPojo>, MyPojo> {

  private final ComboBox<String> _objectId = new ComboBox<>();
  private final TextField _accountId = new TextField();
  private final TextField _personId = new TextField();
  private final DatePicker _startDate = new DatePicker();
  private final DatePicker _endDate = new DatePicker();
  private final IntegerField _age = new IntegerField();
  private final NumberField _amount = new NumberField();

  private final Binder<MyPojo> _binder = new Binder<>();

  // more implementation ...
}
```

Because of the implemented interface I also need to implement `Registration addValueChangeListener(ValueChangeListener<? super ValueChangeEvent<MyPojo>> listener)` What is the best way to implement this? Is there some automation or do I need to do this by hand, e.g. linking my basic input fields method `addValueChangeListener` to the complex  `ValueChangeListener<? super ValueChangeEvent<MyPojo>>`? Or could I somehow use the `_binder` for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than directly implementing the `HasValue` interface, I would recommend  one of the abstract classes that help you with all the nitty gritty details.

In your case, that might be either `AbstractCompositeField` if you want to have full control over the visual representation or `CustomField` if you Vaadin to handle things like an input label.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you chan use a single lister on the binder. I'm in a similar situation and in order to avoid to declare a plethora of listeners, one for each binded field, I just registered on on the binder.
There are two events registrations availabel on the binder. One for any of binded field changed, and the other that triggers for a bunch of situation.
Here the javadoc: https://vaadin.com/api/platform/21.0.8/com/vaadin/flow/data/binder/Binder.html